# Can I open web browser by clicking on the notification created using plyer?

Tags: python, notifications, kivy

I've built a small app for Windows in Python. I used [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/facades/notification.py) to show notifications and it works well. Can I make it open web browser on a certain page by clicking on the notification? I've googled about this, but I wasn't able to find anything useful. Is it possible to do this using this library? If not what should I use?

Comment: Not sure if OS notifications allow such a behavior, but if not, you can use [garden.notification](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.notification) ^^

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the OS you want to target. As you mentioned, custom notification buttons is not yet available in [plyer==1.3.1](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/1.3.1/plyer/facades/notification.py).

However it's still possible to implement some custom widgets per OS. For instance in Android you have the [addAction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#addAction(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action)) method on the Notification object returned by the [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder).
So just like [plyer Android notification](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/1.3.1/plyer/platforms/android/notification.py), you could use [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius) build your notification object.

Or if you don't want to get your hands dirty, there's a [android-notification-buttons](https://github.com/Bakterija/android-notification-buttons) library that does it for you.